# Solr Query Syntax conversion from boolean expression

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm attempting to query solr for documents, given a basic schema with the following field names, data types irrelevant:

I'm attempting to match documents that match at least one of the following:
`occupation, name, age, gender` but i want to OR them together

How do you OR together many terms, and enforce the document to match at least one?

This seems to be failing: `+(name:Sarah age:24 occupation:doctor gender:male)`

How do you convert a boolean expression into solr query syntax? I can't figure out the syntax with `+` and `-` and the default operator for OR.

Comment: What kind of data you want ? Are you want multiple or value for same field like `age` of `25` or `24` or else you want data like `age` is `24' or `gender` is `male` ?

Comment: @User4392892 Both. Male OR 24 (or both)

Answer (score 1):

Still I don't get your requirement but you just need to query like:

```
+(age:24 OR gender:male)
```

Or if you want data for multiple value in same field with OR condition like.
i.e. You get data of `age:24` and `age:25` both.

```
+(age:24 OR age:25 OR gender:male)
```

Then you can:

```
+(age:(24 25) OR gender:male)
```

If it is't your requirement, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it as simple as possible for the client, just go for the dismax[1] or edismax[2] query parser.

Specifically you can configure a request parameter called "qf" :

"The **qf** parameter introduces a list of fields, each of which is assigned a boost factor to increase or decrease that particular field’s importance in the query. For example, the query below:

**qf=fieldOne^2.3 fieldTwo fieldThree^0.4**

assigns fieldOne a boost of 2.3, leaves fieldTwo with the default boost (because no boost factor is specified), and fieldThree a boost of 0.4.

These boost factors make matches in fieldOne much more significant than matches in fieldTwo, which in turn are much more significant than matches in fieldThree." from the wiki

Then you can just pass a free text query, and it will be searched in the fields you specified, giving also different importance to each one, if necessary.

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html